# Python regex ordering issue

Tags: python, regex

I have been running into a problem with python's re module.

This is the simplest version of the issue

```
import re

print re.findall('a|ab','aab')      # ['a', 'a']
print re.findall('ab|a','aab')      # ['a', 'ab']
```

I generate regexes at runtime from a text file and cannot be certain that they will be in the correct order.
Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: he wants the second result(I think at least)...

Comment: Yes, I want the 'ab' in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort them by size... longer first

eg:

```
s_regs = sorted(regexes,key=lambda x:len(x))
s_regs.reverse()
regex = '|'.join(s_regs)
```

Comment: The same but slightly more efficient `regex = '|'.join(sorted(regexes, key=len, reverse=True))`

Comment: I would also use re.escape for every regex.